# Linking inputted text info

Tags: java, eclipse

Right now I have a GUI that when I click on Add Customer a box pops up and I can enter info such as name, address and so on.  When this is done I click Add customer and it adds the info to a .txt file.  Now on the original GUI there is a “Refresh” button that when is pressed it enters the info into a text box called “NameTextCustomers”.  It doesn’t do this.  I have researched it for hours trying to figure it out.  I have a line in the code that says “NameTextCustomers.setText ("File Info Here");”  After I click the refresh button the words “File Info Here” shows up, so that part works.  I’m assuming that the code would be inserted there.  I think this is the last part I have to do for my code to work the way I want it to.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class FVolume extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;

    private JPanel Customers;

    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    JTextArea NameTextCustomers, ExistTextCustomers, NameTextContractors, ExistTextContractors;
    JTextField lengthTextPool, widthTextPool, depthTextPool, volumeTextPool;

    public FVolume(){
        setTitle("Volume Calculator");
        setSize (300, 200);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );

        createCustomers();

        jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        jtabbedPane.addTab("Customer", Customers);

        topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

        /*      CREATE CUSTOMERS    */

    public JPanel createCustomers(){
        Customers = new JPanel();
        Customers.setLayout(null);

        NameTextCustomers = new JTextArea("Select Add Customer to Add Customer.       Select Refresh to Refresh This Pane.");
        NameTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
        NameTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 10, 390, 150);
        Customers.add(NameTextCustomers);

        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        Exit.setBounds(30,170,80,20);
        Exit.addActionListener(this);
        Exit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Customers.add(Exit);

        JButton AddCustomers = new JButton("Add Customer");
        AddCustomers.setBounds(130,170,120,20);
        AddCustomers.setBackground(Color.white);
        Customers.add(AddCustomers);

        JButton Refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
        Refresh.setBounds(260,170,80,20);
        Refresh.setBackground(Color.white);
        Customers.add(Refresh);

        ExistTextCustomers = new JTextArea();
        ExistTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 200, 390, 60);
        ExistTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
        Customers.add(ExistTextCustomers);

        final JTextArea custArea = new JTextArea(6, 30); 
        final JTextArea ExistTextCustomers; 

        ExistTextCustomers = new JTextArea(2, 30); 
        ExistTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true); 
        ExistTextCustomers.setWrapStyleWord(true); 

        AddCustomers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            { 
            Customers.add(new Customer("Customer")); 
        } 
            }); 

        Customers.add(custArea);
        Customers.add(AddCustomers);

        Customers.add(Refresh);
        Refresh.setMnemonic('R');

        Refresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                NameTextCustomers.setText ("File Info Here");
        try
        {
            File custOpen = new File("customer.txt"); 
            FileReader custAreaIn = new FileReader(custOpen); 
            custArea.read(custAreaIn, custOpen.getAbsolutePath()); 
            ExistTextCustomers.setText("File exists and can be read.");
        }
        catch (IOException e3){
            ExistTextCustomers.setText("The file could not be read." + e3.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    );
        return Customers;
}
class Customer extends JFrame
{
    private String[] states = {"AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", 
            "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", 
            "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
            "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
            "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"}; 
            private JComboBox StateList = new JComboBox(states); 
            private JTextField NameText = new JTextField(25); 
            private JTextField AddressText = new JTextField(25); 
            private JTextField CityText = new JTextField(25); 
            private JTextField ZipText = new JTextField(9); 
            private JTextField PhoneText = new JTextField(10); 
            private JTextField ExistTextCustomers = new JTextField(30); 
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

            private AddCustButtonHandler addCusHandler = new AddCustButtonHandler(); 

            public Customer(String who) 
            {
                popUpWindow (who);
            }
            public void popUpWindow(final String who) {
                final JFrame popWindow; 
                popWindow = new JFrame(who); 
                popWindow.setSize(425, 350); 
                popWindow.setLocation(100, 100); 
                popWindow.setVisible(true); 
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

                Container c = new Container(); 

                popWindow.add(c); 

                c.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

                JPanel one = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel two = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel three = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel four = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel five = new JPanel(); 
                JPanel six = new JPanel(); 

                one.add(new JLabel(who + " Name ")); 
                one.add(NameText); 
                two.add(new JLabel("Address ")); 
                two.add(AddressText); 
                three.add(new JLabel("City ")); 
                three.add(CityText); 
                four.add(new JLabel("State ")); 
                StateList.setSelectedIndex(0); 
                four.add(StateList); 
                four.add(new JLabel("ZIP")); 
                four.add(ZipText); 
                four.add(new JLabel("Phone")); 
                four.add(PhoneText); 
                JButton addwho = new JButton("Add " + who); 
                addwho.setMnemonic('A'); 
                JButton close = new JButton("Exit"); 
                close.setMnemonic('C'); 
                JButton deleteFile = new JButton("Delete File"); 
                deleteFile.setMnemonic('D'); 
                five.add(addwho); 
                five.add(close); 
                five.add(deleteFile); 
                ExistTextCustomers.setEditable(false); 
                ExistTextCustomers.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); 

                six.add(ExistTextCustomers); 
                c.add(one); 
                c.add(two); 
                c.add(three); 
                c.add(four); 
                c.add(five); 
                c.add(six); 

                deleteFile.setToolTipText("Delete File"); 
                addwho.setToolTipText("Add "+ who); 
                close.setToolTipText("Exit");

                if (who == "Customer")
                    addwho.addActionListener(addCusHandler);
                close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        NameText.setText(""); 
                        AddressText.setText(""); 
                        CityText.setText(""); 
                        ZipText.setText(""); 
                        PhoneText.setText(""); 
                        ExistTextCustomers.setText(""); 
                        popWindow.dispose();
                    }
                }
                );
                deleteFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        ExistTextCustomers.setText("");
                        if (who.equals("Customer")) {
                            File file = new File("Customer.txt"); 
                            boolean cusFileDeleted = file.delete(); 
                            if (cusFileDeleted) {
                                ExistTextCustomers 
                                .setText("Customer file has been deleted"); 
                            } else {
                                ExistTextCustomers 
                                .setText("There was an error in deleting file"); 
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            class AddCustButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent addCusHandler) { 
                    int StateIndex; 
                    try { 
                        File file = new File("Customer.txt");
                        boolean success = file.createNewFile();
                        if (success) {
                            ExistTextCustomers
                            .setText("Customer.txt file created file added");
                        } else if (file.canWrite()) {
                            ExistTextCustomers
                            .setText("Writing data to Customer.txt, file added");
                        } else {
                            ExistTextCustomers.setText("Cannot create file: Customer.txt");
                        }
                        try {
                            FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter("Customer.txt", true);
                            fileW.write(NameText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(AddressText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(CityText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            StateIndex = StateList.getSelectedIndex();
                            fileW.write(states[StateIndex]);
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(ZipText.getText());
                            fileW.write(",");
                            fileW.write(PhoneText.getText());
                            fileW.write("\r\n");
                            fileW.close();
                            ExistTextCustomers.setText("A new Customer has been added!");
                            FileReader fileR = new FileReader("Customer.txt");
                            BufferedReader buffIn = new BufferedReader(fileR);
                            String textData = buffIn.readLine();
                            buffIn.close(); 

                        }
                        catch (IOException e1) { 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "ERROR", 2);
                        }
                        NameText.setText(""); 
                        AddressText.setText(""); 
                        CityText.setText(""); 
                        ZipText.setText(""); 
                        PhoneText.setText(""); 
                        }
                    catch (IOException e1) { 
                    }

                }
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            }
                private void Exit_pressed(){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }


                public static void main(String[] args){
                    JFrame frame = new FVolume();
                    frame.setSize(420, 350);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                }

}
```

[image: Flow of events]

After clicking the Refresh button, it should enter the info into the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured out the issue with your code. took some time, but it's not too complicated.
But first, don't put too more than one class in a file, this is a bad practice (and made it much harder to go through your code.

The problem is that after you press "Add costumer" in the "customer" window you need to send that data to the main application window. how to do that?

Add `FVolume parent;` to the `customer` class and change the constructor of `Customer` class to receive not only a String, but an object of FVolume:

```
public Customer(String who, FVolume _parent) 
    {
        popUpWindow (who);
        parent = _parent;
    }
```

and you have access to the main window from the customer.
Now you need to be able to change the text of `NameTextCustomers`, so create a new method in FVolume class that allows to change it from outside:

```
public void setField(String str)
    {
        NameTextCustomers.setText(str);
        NameTextCustomers.validate();
    }
```

Next thing will be to call this method when someone press "Add customer" in the "Costumer" window. you already have a listener, but let's change it's `actionPerformed` method a bit so it won't only save the String to your file, but will also set it in `NameTextCustomers`. (I didn't put the last lines of the method, but no change there)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent addCusHandler) { 
    int StateIndex; 
    try { 
        File file = new File("Customer.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean success = file.createNewFile();
        if (success) {
            ExistTextCustomers
            .setText("Customer.txt file created file added");
        } else if (file.canWrite()) {
            ExistTextCustomers
            .setText("Writing data to Customer.txt, file added");
        } else {
            ExistTextCustomers.setText("Cannot create file: Customer.txt");
        }
        try {
            FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter("Customer.txt", true);
            sb.append(NameText.getText());
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(AddressText.getText());
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(CityText.getText());
            sb.append(",");
            StateIndex = StateList.getSelectedIndex();
            sb.append(states[StateIndex]);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(ZipText.getText());
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(PhoneText.getText());
            sb.append("\r\n");
            fileW.write(sb.toString());
            parent.setField(sb.toString());
            fileW.close();
            ExistTextCustomers.setText("A new Customer has been added!");
            FileReader fileR = new FileReader("Customer.txt");
            BufferedReader buffIn = new BufferedReader(fileR);
            String textData = buffIn.readLine();
            buffIn.close();
```

The only remaining issue is related to the construction of the `Customer` object. we need to add the FVolume object to the constructor, but we shouldn't add it to `costumers` panel, since it's a different frame:

```
AddCustomers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            { 
            new Customer("Customer", FVolume.this); 
        } 
     });
```

This only made it work, and I tried to touch the code only when it was absolutely necessary, I didn't try to change the coding style.

Comment: not sure it's related,but the line `if (who == "Customer")` is wrong. you should write it like that: `if (who.equals("Customer))`.

Comment: @Mike - Can you put some more order to your question - what does work, what should happen, what doesn't happen... I know you detailed all that but it seems to me a bit confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @MByD: I can add info to the text document.  Then when I click the refresh button on the GUI the following text shows up in the “NameTextCustomers” JText area (File Info Here).  I put this line of code in just to see if I could make something show up in the text box.  I know it’s hard to follow and explain.

Comment: If I got you right, you should use `custOpen.getAbsolutePath()` instead of `custOpen.toString()`

Comment: @MByD: Still doing the same.  Would it help if I edited the code above so you can run it?

Comment: OK, also, can you put a print screen of the application to clarify the problem?

Comment: Well, if I got you right, you want to see some info in the `JTextArea`s (e.g. NameText, AddressText, etc.), but looking at your code, I don't see any place where you set the text of those fields.

Comment: Are you talking about after I enter the info and click add customer?  I guess that's where I'm confused.  I'm not sure what is missing and where it needs to be inputted.

Comment: @MByD: I see that it is working.  My next question is, (and I'm looking into this as well), is to drop each text on a new line.  So Name on the top, then below it the address, and so on.  Also I noticed that this info gets inputted to the text box when you click add customer.  Is there a way for this info to be inputted when the Refresh button is clicked.  Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Very simple. you actually did that, `sb.append("\n");` will add a new line character to the text, so you can use it instead of `sb.append(",");` in any place that you want to start new line (where sb is defined of course...)

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  Now the only thing left would be the Refresh button situation I mentioned above.  Is it done where you have addCusHandler?

Comment: The refresh changes the text, you don't need it since the text has already changed